# Firebase cloud functions deployment error "Function failed on loading user code" with empty error message

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I'm having this problem intermittently and on different functions that I am deploying. This can always be solved by redeploying the functions that failed with the `--only function:` flag.

I turned on the `--debug` switch, hoping that I could see what was failing, but I got nothing so far. The only thing that is immediately apparent is a bunch of GET request (that always respond w/ 200-OK) that I assume are linked to each functions:

```
[2019-07-01T10:32:19.177Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/FOOBARpYW5LWhlYXQtMTM5y91cy1jZW50cmFsM9jb3B5RmlyZXN0b3JlRG9jFOOBAR

[a bit further down]

[2019-07-01T10:32:19.407Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 content-type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, vary=X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding, date=Mon, 01 Jul 2019 10:32:19 GMT, server=ESF, cache-control=private, x-xss-protection=0, x-frame-options=SAMEORIGIN, x-content-type-options=nosniff, alt-svc=quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,44,43,39", accept-ranges=none, transfer-encoding=chunked
```

This back and forth goes on for a few minutes, and the number of requests diminishes as the functions get successfully or unsuccessfully deployed. In case of a failure, the log is

```
⚠  functions[myFunctionName(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Function failed on loading user code. Error message:
```

One particularity is that my functions are all written in separate files, which are in turn combined/transpiled with Babel and loaded with `requires`. This never seemed to have caused problems in the two year, but we've been using more and more cloud fn, so who knows...

Any idea as to how to debug this further???

Comment: Happens all the time to me too.  It comes and goes, I can't find a pattern.  Just run the same command with the same code against and again and eventually it works.

Comment: Have you ever tried the logging options as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging)? Besides the simple `stdout` or `stderr`, you can give it a try using Stackdriver for complete logs, which could help you find out the cause for the issue. Could you please take a look at it and sees if it helps you?

Comment: Hi @gso_gabriel I've changed my setup quite a lot since and this issue is not reproducible anymore. However, the link you provided is for runtime logging and my problem was when deploying the function (i.e. before the funciton is ever run). If I would encounter this problem again, I would investigate the operations via the gcloud cli (`gcloud functions logs` and co)

Comment: The issue for me was having a `required` package in my `index.js` file, but had not ran `npm i` on the package in the functions folder.